# Product of two fields annotation

Tags: django, django-models

I currently have a line in my Django app like this:

```
db.execute("SELECT SUM(price * qty) FROM inventory_orderline WHERE order_id = %s", [self.id])
```

I'd rather perform this through the models interface provided my Django, but can't find any references.

I'm pretty sure this can be done with an annotation, but the examples only cover a few of them and I can't find a list in the documentation.

I'd like to do something like this:

```
self.line_items.annotate(lineprice=Product('orderline__price', 'orderline__qty')).aggregate(Sum('lineprice'))
```

Can anyone suggest an annotation class to use to perform the multiplication?  Even better, a link to the API listing all these annotation/aggregation classes?

Answer (score 3):

It's not clearly documented, but this can be done with the `F()` function:

```
from django.db.models import F

self.line_items.annotate(lineprice=F('orderline__price') * F('orderline__qty')).aggregate(Sum('lineprice'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there [aren't enough](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#aggregation-functions) inbuilt Aggregate functions and specifically, there is not one for Product.

But that doesn't limit you in any way other than having to write a "non-concise" ORM query. Specifically for your case, you should be able to do:

```
self.line_items.extra(select=("lineprice": "orderline__price*orderline__qty")).aggregate(Sum('lineprice'))
```

Comment: Thanks, first time I've seen that technique.

Comment: I can make this work, but I have to use SUM(price*qty) as it doesn't follow double'_' relationships, and the aggregate can't see the 'lineprice' field.  Still less than desirable I'm afraid

Comment: This won't work. The `aggregate` can't see things introduced by `extra` (also the `select` expects a dictionary, so it would need `{}` rather than `()`)

Comment: This doesn't work. Why would you post a solution that doesn't work.